# SharePoint Web Parts can not be connected via hyperlink fields

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

In short:
I'm trying to filter an XSLTListViewWebPart based on what is selected in another XSLTListViewWebPart. Using a String field as connection this is working fine. Using a hyperlink field no data is displayed.

In more detail:
I have two lists, say `Accounts` and `Projects`. Both have a hyperlink field `accountURL`.
All accounts have different accountURLs. Different projects can have the same value for accountURL. Both are displayed on a page using the XSLTListViewWebPart.
The simple goal is to filter the `Projects` list based on which item is selected in the `Accounts` list using the `accountURL` field. So I established a web part connection using the `acountURL` as a filter. Alas, when an item in the `Accounts` list is selected no items are showwn in the `Projects` list although I double checked that there are matching values.
When using a string field instead of a hyperlink field for `accountURL` everything works like a charm. Problem is, I need the hyperlink field.

Is this desired behaviour? Do you have any suggestions for a workaround?
(I already tried converting the hyperlink field to a string field via a calculated column which did not work out either.)

All was and is to be done in the web interface or SP-Designer. Coding a WSP is not an option for this problem. As I'm not quite familiar with the correct terminus technicus I use field and column interchangeably.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone on the Microsoft forum suggested the following [workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/a23921e0-be32-48e8-96e5-0a7ebc21a90e#a23921e0-be32-48e8-96e5-0a7ebc21a90e) which does its job well:

- Add a hidden text column to both lists.
- Use a workflow which is triggered on item creation and update to copy the value of the hyperlink column to the hidden text column.
- Connect both webparts using the hidden column as filter.

Nonetheless, I still wonder whether it is possible to use hyperlink columns or other special columns for filtering. I also had the problem that I cannot use a person column as lookup.

Does anyone know if whether there ist some kind of overview
which column types can be used for filtering/formulas/lookup/...?

Cheers,

Ben